# Python - Checking an input for numbers, uppercase, lowercase letters and special characters

Tags: python, numbers, uppercase, lowercase, string-length

I am trying to create a little program in which the user enters a password into the console. The program then checks whether the password is weak, medium or strong depending what the user has typed in.

I need to check how many uppercase, lowercase and numbers have been entered and then tell the user how strong their password is.

I have most of the program completed, but since I haven't really used Python for long I am not too familiar with anything advanced, bear in mind younger people have to understand this code too who are not going to be good at coding themselves.

So far I have:

```
#Welcome the user to the application.
print("Hello, please enter a password to check how secure it is");

#Set a variable called MinPass and set a value of 6.
MinPass = 6;

#Set a variable called MaxPass and set a value of 12.
MaxPass = 12;

#Set variable EnteredPass and wait for user input
EnteredPass = input("Password: ");

while len(EnteredPass) < MinPass:
    print("Your password is too short, please enter a longer password and try again")
    EnteredPass = input("Password: ");

while len(EnteredPass) > MaxPass:
    print("Your password is too long, please shorten it and try again!");
    EnteredPass = input("Password: ");
```

Please note, this is for educational purposes only. I'm not planning on making a program in an intent to steal random password. It's for a part of a course that's going on in my school!

Comment: You haven't made much of an attempt yourself yet, have you? Have you looked at the [`str` type methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters They've set some variables :) I'm just wondering what a "womabt" is :)

Comment: Although, I have answered your question and there are many more people on SO that can answer the questions, I would advice you to take a look at the documentation of python(or whichever language you are learning), before asking questions on SO. Even the best of the programmers work by continuously referring to the documentation of the language. Also, the documentation provided of python is very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This contains a few more-advanced concepts, but should be easy enough to follow:

```
import string

def long_enough(pw):
    'Password must be at least 6 characters'
    return len(pw) >= 6

def short_enough(pw):
    'Password cannot be more than 12 characters'
    return len(pw) <= 12

def has_lowercase(pw):
    'Password must contain a lowercase letter'
    return len(set(string.ascii_lowercase).intersection(pw)) > 0

def has_uppercase(pw):
    'Password must contain an uppercase letter'
    return len(set(string.ascii_uppercase).intersection(pw)) > 0

def has_numeric(pw):
    'Password must contain a digit'
    return len(set(string.digits).intersection(pw)) > 0

def has_special(pw):
    'Password must contain a special character'
    return len(set(string.punctuation).intersection(pw)) > 0

def test_password(pw, tests=[long_enough, short_enough, has_lowercase, has_uppercase, has_numeric, has_special]):
    for test in tests:
        if not test(pw):
            print(test.__doc__)
            return False
    return True

def main():
    pw = input('Please enter a test password:')
    if test_password(pw):
        print('That is a good password!')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work the best. I've tested it and it's what I'm after and I can understand it relatively well! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions:-

```
    isalnum() # To check for alpha numeric characters
    isalpha() # To check for the presence of only alphabets
```

for eg.

```
    password = input("Enter the password: ")
    if password.isalnum() == False:
        print "Password should contain atleast one special character or number"
    if password.isalpha() == False:
        print "Password should contains atleast some alphabets."
```

To check for the presence of capital or small letters you can use this:-

```
    temp = passsword.lower()
    if temp  == password:
        print "Password should contain atleast one capital letters"
```

How it Works?
Although this code is self-explanatory, there is nothing rocket-science about it, I will explain it since, you seem to be a beginner to me:-

```
    str.isalnum() returns False if the string contains some non alphabet characters
    str.isalpha() returns false if the string does not contain a single alphabet
```

By creating

```
  temp
```

I am storing a copy of the password which is lowercase. So if the password variable contains some capital letters then the

```
    temp == password
```

will return False, and you can find out whether the string contains some capital letters or not.
As pointed out by @MartijnPieters, you can use

```
    if not password.isalnum():
```

also instead of

```
    if password.isalnum() == False:
```

Although, the first way is more "pythonic"

Comment: This seems like a suitable solution... Thank you! I will try this now and get back to you on how it works!

Comment: Do *not* test against `== False`. Use `if not password.isalnum():` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MartijnPieters. I have added your suggestion in the final answer.

Answer (score -2):

Write MATLAB code to check for the strength of an entered password, the code should output: ‘weak’, ‘medium’, ‘strong’, and very strong’ depending on the length of the password, the use of both capital and small letters, the use of numbers and special character.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This doesn't really answer the question of OP *how* to check a password.